# Weather app crashes on emulator

Tags: android, xml, json, parsing, weather

**SOLVED** THANK YOU VERY MUCH EVERYONE

Helle, and first of all thanks for clicking on my question. I've made an app thay gets a json file of the weather. It then parses this JSON file to get the weather variables like temperature etc. It displays those variables in textView's. The problem is that when I press the button (on my emulator) it says "Unfortunaly, (app name) has stopped working". Below you can find the code I used to make all this. Help will be appreciated. If you need any more files like activity_main.xml, strings.xml,... just ask.

Thank you for helping **THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR HELPING, I THINK THERE ARE 3 MORE ERROR TO BE SOLVED, BUT I DON'T UNDERSTAND THESE ERROR LOGS, I JUST STARTED CODING, THANK YOU EVERYONE FOR THE HELP (YOU CAN FIND THEM AT THE BOTTOM OF THE POST**

### MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.thelexapp;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Perform action on click   
            try {
                getURLforweather();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

} 

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

    if (location != null) {

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        String longitudestring = String.valueOf(longitude);
        String latitudestring = String.valueOf(latitude);

        String url =     "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q="
                + longitudestring
                + ","
                + latitudestring
                +   "&format=json&num_of_days=1&key=hv3rd4u49qdmf6q3hp5apy6b";


        parseJson(url);
String temp_C = null;
        String windspeedKmph = null;
        String weatherDesc = null;

        TCWSKMPH(temp_C, windspeedKmph);
        WD(weatherDesc);

    }
}

public void parseJson (String url) {
    DefainputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        in
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) { 


    storeJSONVariables(result);

}

public void 
            try {
                JSONObject oneObject = jArrayCurrent.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray jArrayWeatherDesc =   jObject.getJSONArray("weatherDesc");
                String temp_C = oneObject.getString("temp_C");
                String windspeedKmph = oneObject.getString("windspeedKmph");

                   // Pulling items from the array
                        String weatherDesc = twoObject.getString("value");  

                        WD(weatherDesc);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                    }


public void TCWSKMPH(String temp_C, String windspeedKmph) {

    if(temp_C != null || windspeedKmph != null) {
         RwindspeedKmph.nextInt(max - min + 1) + min;

        temp_C = getString(a);
        windspeedKmph = getString(b);
    }

    TextView temptext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.temperature);
    TextView sowtext = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.windspeed);
    temptext.setText("TEMPERATURE: " + temp_C);
    sowtext.setText("WINDSPEED: " + windspeedKmph);
}

public void WD(String weatherDesc) {
    String descriptionofweather = weatherDesc;
```

### LogCat:

```
03-01 11:57:40.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2471):     at com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity.TCWSKMPH(MainActivity.java:190)
03-01 11:57:40.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2471):     at com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity.getURLforweather(MainActivity.java:92)
03-01 11:57:40.760: E/AndroidRuntime(2471):     at com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:42)
```

Comment: Where do you called this **getPositionAndGetWheater()** method? and also post your logcat for better understanding

Comment: It would be helpful to see the stack trace when the app crashes to see what is causing the problem.

Comment: Uhm, never noticed that I used it nowhere, but if I press the button, it run the getweather (i think) cause the text changes to "Unable to get weather information" (cause i don't know how to use GPS in emulator, so it returns null)

Comment: @user3357521 try into real Device and but where is your `Button` `onclick(...)` event? you are a _REAL ROCKET PROGRAMMER_.

Comment: i don't have a real device, i am making this app for a friend, i have an iphone :s

Comment: @user3357521 : `if I press the button` which button you are pressing please provide more details as much as possible.

Comment: That's not the stacktrace. You should look under "LogCat" tab.

Comment: @user3357521 if you found useful one or more answers you should upvote them. Then, if there's an answer which solves the problem (or the best one if there are many) you should accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `max=0` and `min=20`, `int a` and/or `int b` becomes a negative number-> `n<=0` in the LogCat.

Also,
 1. In emulator, you will have to pass location lat-long values. Through either Eclipse-DDMS  or pass values directly in code (for the purpose of testing the rest of your code.)
for-"..cause i don't know how to use GPS in emulator, so it returns null"
 2. In your current code, in the `else` part of `if(location!=null)`,

```
final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);  
textViewToChange.setText("Unable to get weather information.");  
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Same `...id.textView1` for both- `text` and `textViewToChange`

To convert int to String:
String a = String.valueOf(int value here);

check: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm

Comment: **thank you** i solved them all except for number 1 , i don't know how to pass lat and long values, i don't even know where the Eclipse-DDMS is, i'l google it and hope for the best

Comment: Check: http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MaR30u3PhrU

Comment: thank you i think i passed in long and lat values, but there are still some error in the random int part, i changed max to 20 and min to 0 , but i think it's haveing troubles with converting the int to a string... do u know any solution? thank you for your help **;)**

Comment: i'l accept ur answer when it works, cause otherwise people may maybe think it's solved :)

Comment: all errors solved, but it still takes random values, and i'm sure i passed in long and lat values in the Eclipse DDMS :s

Comment: i really need to test it with the real long and lat values, cause this json parser looks scary and it will probably give an error to

Comment: Did u send the values at runtime? Can try placing values directly in the url ..to test

Comment: i used this url : http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=42.02%2C-122.36&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=apikey     but it still says unable to get weather information :s any ideas? thank you user2450263 for all the help ;)

Comment: the link is wrong tho because it doesn't have a api key (for safety reasons, and it is using xml instead of json , but it is the correct one in the code so don't worry

Answer (score 0):

The LogCat shows that there's an error here (line 173 of MainActivity.java):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: -19
03-01 11:46:33.080: E/AndroidRuntime(2369):     at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:175)
03-01 11:46:33.080: E/AndroidRuntime(2369):     at com.example.thelexapp.MainActivity.TCWSKMPH(MainActivity.java:173)
```

In particular the input parameter of the method "nextInt" is negative